# Minor Cycle Design in a Cyclic Scheduler

Tags: algorithm, embedded, scheduled-tasks, constraints, scheduler

I am currently designing a cyclic scheduling algorithm for an embedded system. The system will be an embedded web server and the design of the scheduler will be based off of the advice I received in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952109/looking-for-a-comparison-of-different-scheduling-algorithms-for-a-finite-state-m).

What sort of things should I be looking at when it comes to constraining task execution during the minor cycle time of my scheduler?

Comment: @andersoj I dont have code now, I am in planning phase.

Comment: Refer to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952109/looking-for-a-comparison-of-different-scheduling-algorithms-for-a-finite-state-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For embedded systems, it's pretty common for the execution time of task to be fairly static (i.e. low variability). In such cases, it's usually easier to properly profile the execution time of each task and design the timing of your scheduler's cycles accordingly.

If your tasks will indeed have highly variable execution time and you want to incorporate constraints, you will still need to profile the system to have an idea of what needs to be checked on. You would then create separate process that runs in an interrupt context to check the status of executing tasks. If the task violates a constraint, the process then needs to inform the scheduler and perform the appropriate cleanup.

Some theory can be found starting in Section 1.5.3 in [this module](http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/Webcourse-contents/IIT%20Kharagpur/Embedded%20systems/Pdf/Lesson-29.pdf). And some code examples can be found in [these notes](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/realtime/restricted/notes/staticscheduling.html).

As you can see, both are from full courses on the topic and a proper discussion of such a topic would indeed take an entire multi-week course. But those papers should at least get you started.